# SelectDateWidget: substitute day in case of wrong day

Tags: django

**Django 1.11**

The problem: if day is absent in a month, the user gets validation error: "Enter a valid date".

Before this validation error occurred, I'd like to use this function:

```
def ceil_day(year, month, day):
    __weekday, number_of_days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
    return min(day, number_of_days_in_month)
```

In other words, I'd like to substitute the date: if a user input a non-existing day, let it be the last day of that very month.

Could you help me understand how to do that.

[image]

```
class FrameDateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = FrameDate
            exclude = []

            years = range(1800, datetime.datetime.now().year + 1)

            widgets = {
                'frame': forms.HiddenInput(),
                'from_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=years),
                'through_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=years)
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that by implementing the **clean()** method as follows:

```
class FrameDateForm(ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        super(ModelForm, self).clean()

        day = int(self.data.get('from_date_day', 0))
        month = int(self.data.get('from_date_month', 0))
        year = int(self.data.get('from_date_year', 0))
        if day and year and month:
            self.cleaned_data['from_date'] = datetime.date(
                year, month, ceil_day(year, month, day))
            if 'from_date' in self._errors:
                del self._errors['from_date']
        return self.cleaned_data
```

The clean() method always gets called on form validation.  So we can expect that ceil_day() is always applied to the *from_date* field.  In case of the non-existing day error, we need to clear the error of the *from_date* field before returning.

Comment: I have added the clean method. And nothing changes. I put a breakpoint in it and the debugger doesn't stop. I think that even before validation they tried to build a date out of information at hand. And of course, an exception is risen.

Comment: That means the debugger didn't reach the clean() method due to the raised exception?  Could you share the detail (stack trace) of the exception?  (In my test, I'm not observing any exceptions raised, and the snippet is working as expected.)